# Could you please explain this while loop in a simple way?

Tags: python, while-loop

You need to write a loop that takes the numbers in a given list named num_list:
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]

Your code should add up the odd numbers in the list, but only up to the first 5 odd numbers together. If there are more than 5 odd numbers, you should stop at the fifth. If there are fewer than 5 odd numbers, add all of the odd numbers.

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 59, 84, 69, 113, 166]

count_odd = 0
list_sum = 0
i = 0
len_num_list = len(num_list)

while (count_odd < 5) and (i < len_num_list): 
    if num_list[i] % 2 != 0:
        list_sum += num_list[i]
        count_odd += 1
    i += 1

print ("The numbers of odd numbers added are: {}".format(count_odd))
print ("The sum of the odd numbers added is: {}".format(list_sum))
```

Comment: How about an explanation of what you don't understand?

Comment: i = 0 ,   (i < len_num_list),   list_sum += num_list[i],  i += 1

Comment: This is what I do not understand in this code.

Comment: You want to iterate through all the elements in the array. Let’s say you have 10 elements. You might want to access array[0] to array[9]. What you have to do is to use a variable named `i` and starting from 0, increment it’s value until it is 9. That’s what the while loop is doing.

Comment: Produces the sum and count of the first 5 odd numbers in the list (`list_sum`, `count_odd`).  The while loop checks for the count reaching 5 or the end of the list. `i` is the index of the element currently being processes (stating at zero which is the index of the first element). `num_list[i] % 2 != 0` checks if the element is odd.